# Spring boot 2 Redis cache default client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am using Spring Boot 2 and this dependency to use redis cache:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
```

As I read before `Letucce` is a default client for Redis. But, when I started to configure it with properties (even default) it become failed.

```
spring:
 redis:
  lettuce:
    pool:
      max-active: 8
      max-idle: 8
      max-wait: -1
      min-idle: 0
```

To recover service I can add common-pool2:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-pool2', version: '2.8.1'
```

It looks like spring boot starts to use this pool only after setting properties.

So, the question is what exact redis client is used by Spring Boot by default and what properties are set by default?

Comment: If yours is a maven project you can run `mvn dependency:tree` to see the list of the actual dependencies and their versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have to say that default behavior is not async. That is why there are no pools used at all. Adding the `Lettuce` client leads us to use an external pool.